# Error with amsmath and an equation in Latex

Tags: amsmath

I am new to writing on this website so bear with me if I am doing something not right.
So I am trying to put this equation in Latex,

[image: Equation]

I have used MathType to write it and get its latex code, here,

```
\[\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \cos \varphi  & \sin \varphi   \\
   -\sin \varphi \ \  & \cos \varphi \   \\
\end{matrix} \right]\ \left[ \begin{align}
  & x \\ 
 & y \\ 
\end{align} \right]=\left[ \begin{align}
  & 0 \\ 
 & P \\ 
\end{align} \right]+\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \cos {{\theta }_{1}} & \sin {{\theta }_{1}}  \\
   -\sin {{\theta }_{1}}\ \  & \cos {{\theta }_{1}}\   \\
\end{matrix} \right]\left( \left[ \begin{align}
  & 0 \\ 
 & M \\ 
\end{align} \right]+\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \cos {{\theta }_{2}} & \sin {{\theta }_{2}}  \\
   -\sin {{\theta }_{2}}\ \  & \cos {{\theta }_{2}}\   \\
\end{matrix} \right]\left[ \begin{align}
  & 0 \\ 
 & D \\ 
\end{align} \right] \right)\]
```

however when I enter it on overleaf I get the following errors:

```
Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;

(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.378 \end{align}
                  \right]=\left[ \begin{align}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.



Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;

(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.381 \end{align}
                  \right]+\left[ \begin{matrix}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.



Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;

(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.387 \end{align}
                  \right]+\left[ \begin{matrix}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.



Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;

(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.393 \end{align}
                  \right] \right)\]
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Thank you for your help in advance.
```

Comment: `align` is a top level environment that starts math, change them all to `matrix`

Comment: Why are you using `align` inside those structures? All your matrices should be mare using the `bmatrix` env, it is like `matrix` but automatically adds `[]`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The thing is I am also new to Latex so I am using MathType to do all the work of coding it to Latex format. Hence I am unaware of the formating. Thanks again though!

Comment: Just a quick question. So I used the solution you guys offered and it works great. However, I now have a long equation with half of it off the page. Can we make it smaller or decrease its font size so it comes on one line? Again thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's convenient to use such a tool as MathType if it outputs erroneous code.

Some practice will make you able to type in the code directly. Here's a working version.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \varphi  & \sin \varphi \\
   -\sin \varphi & \cos \varphi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ P \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \theta_{1} & \sin \theta_{1}  \\
   -\sin \theta_{1} & \cos \theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\left(
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ M \end{bmatrix}
  +
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \theta_{2} & \sin \theta_{2}  \\
   -\sin \theta_{2} & \cos \theta_{2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ D \end{bmatrix}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

As you see, no “backslash-space” and no useless braces. For bracket-delimited matrices, use `bmatrix`. It is completely equivalent to

```
\left[\begin{matrix}
... matrix rows ...
\end{matrix}\right]
```

but there's little doubt that

```
\begin{bmatrix}
... matrix rows ...
\end{bmatrix}
```

is easier and clearer code.

[image]

In order to solve an overfull, in this case the standard way is to use `multline*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \varphi  & \sin \varphi \\
   -\sin \varphi & \cos \varphi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
\\
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ P \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \theta_{1} & \sin \theta_{1}  \\
   -\sin \theta_{1} & \cos \theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\left(
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ M \end{bmatrix}
  +
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \theta_{2} & \sin \theta_{2}  \\
   -\sin \theta_{2} & \cos \theta_{2}  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ D \end{bmatrix}
\right)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering about something; you may have noticed the long equation hence it goes all the way and past the margin so will just enclosing it with `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` solve the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DailyReader I added some code

Comment: my reply is really a bit late but thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DailyReader You're welcome!